# Headset Mic Not Recognized On Boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, sound, 20.04, microphone

I am on a ThinkPad laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I plug in my earbuds with a built-in mic to the 3.5 mm jack, everything works perfectly. However, if the earbuds are already plugged in when I turn the laptop on, the mic is not recognized by Ubuntu. This issue does not happen if I boot into Windows (my laptop is dual-booted).

Edit: The issue is fixed if I unplug and re-plugin the earbuds after boot, this is my current solution to the problem.

Comment: Does it fix it if you unplug and replug?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry for not mentioning that, i meant to in the original question

Comment: Does this command fix the issue `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`? If run that after reboot it should reset your audio devices. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: When I run that command I can hear the audio devices resetting, but for some strange reason the mic still isn't detected afterwards. Unplugging and replugging after that command still works though